# what is the reason behind the snake with several gods and goddess

Tags: gods, symbolism, vahana

I saw some of the god's and goddess having snake with them is there any particular reason for this. And also I want to know each and every deities having some birds and animals domestic and wild including navagraha's. What is the importance and role of the snakes with deities?

Comment: _"deities having some birds and animals, How they are mingled? "_ There is story behind those animals who associated with Gods as their vahana(Travelling source). It's not possible to tell all storied in single answer. You should asked about them saperately like this.. "_How Garurh become vahana of Vishnu OR How Nandi associated with Shiva"_ something like this.

Comment: Ok asking only snake